# PHP: Export to CSV with superscript

Tags: php, html, csv, subscript, superscript

I have parsed a page with a table and I have an array with data. I need to export this data to CSV file, but want to save formating, especially superscipt. Here is my code:

```
    $filename = 'data.csv';

    $arraySup['data1'] = 'Value1';
    $arraySup['data2'] = 'Value2';
    $arraySup['data3'] = '<div><b>6</b><sup>3</sup></div>';
    $arraySup['data4'] = '<div><b>2</b><sup>1 1/2</sup><br>49.67</div>';

    $handle = fopen($filename, 'a+');
    fputcsv($handle, $arraySup);
    fclose($handle);
```

I need to get this on output in my CSV file.
Here is link to image what I want to get. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/94yfxrveug5uce4/superscript_example.png?dl=0

I will appreciate any help in this question.

Comment: csv is for data. it is not a "formatting" format. you can embed all the html you want, but since csv is NOT html, it's not going to be rendered by a browser.

Comment: CSV files do not preserve formatting.

Comment: Your image has nothing to do with CSV... could you provide the expected CSV data instead?

Comment: You won't get this with a CSV file, because a csv file contains no formatting information.... if you want to create a real Excel file that does support formatting such as superscripts, then look at one of the many libraries for creating real Excel files in PHP

Comment: Thanks for advice and answers, will use php excel library for that. I was thinking, it's something simpler